# Ubuntu 16.04 pyvirtualdisplay ValueError

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, scrapy

I'm getting the following error when trying to start pyvirtualdisplay:

```
>>> from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
>>> display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768)).start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 38, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 33, in __init__
    AbstractDisplay.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.display = self.search_for_display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py", line 66, in search_for_display
    ls = [int(x.split('X')[1].split('-')[0]) for x in self.lock_files()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py", line 66, in <listcomp>
    ls = [int(x.split('X')[1].split('-')[0]) for x in self.lock_files()]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'O'
```

I installed Xvfb:

```
apt-get install xvfb
```

I can't figure out why is this happening. I'm using Python3.6, Ubuntu 16.04. I need to run some Scrapy scripts with Selenium and `--headless` mode isn't appropriate so this seems to be the only option:

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Any alternatives suggestion or any other help with this?

Comment: How is the error `display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768)).start()` related to `Selenium`?

Comment: Not really related. I'm trying to run Chrome without Display, like so: driver = webdriver.Chrome() and without any flags. It's returning error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed. From what I read many would suggest to try and run Dispaly first which seems resonable. I'm running this on my local machine without problems but here Selenium is using my native browser installs. It's working fine on both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I tried this one strait from the container terminal: `google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox "example.com"` as root. The error: `[0419/163726.285044:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`

Comment: You need to execute as a `non-root` user for sure